# There is a sequence of operations on grammars of a string that strictly decreases the size of grammars down to the smallest grammer.

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I'm trying to figure out the *smallest grammar problem*, which yes I know is impossible since it's such a hard problem, but humor me for a sec.

Let $g$ be a smallest grammar for the string $s$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c, \dots, z\}$, ie for formal language theorists, $s \in \Sigma^*$.

For example $s = abaaabbaba$ and $g$ might be:

$$
g \to AaaAbAa \\
A \to ab
$$

Well we could undo the involvement of the variable $A$ in one step by substituting the RHS of $A$ to wherever it occurs in other rules.  If this doesn't result in a larger sized grammar then the use of the variable was not required, so let's only work with "minimal" smallest grammars.

### The topic statement

*Since there is a sequence of such operations all the way to $g \to s = abaaabbaba$, then there must be a sequence of reverse operations leading from the grammar $g \to s$ all the way to one of its smallest grammars.  And these operations can be chosen such that they drop the size of the intermediate grammar each time (strictly decreasing size).*

The reverse operation used above would be taking any set of occurances of the contents of some variable $A$, ie some occurences in the grammar definition, and replacing them with a symbol for $A$ and adding the rule for $A$ if it wasn't already.

Comment: Wouldn't the shortest grammar for $s = abaaabbaba$ be $S\to \mathtt{abaaabbaba}$? I don't think it makes sense to talk about a grammar for a single string; it only makes sense to talk about a grammar for a *set* of strings.

Comment: @MJD The size function of a grammar is defined to be the total number of symbols on the RHS of all the rules.  So your $S \to \dots$ has $10$ symbols while my grammar has a total of $9$ symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Somewhat) informal argument in a proof by induction by the number $n$ of elements in your string:

The statement is clearly true for $n=1$ (the initial production is minimal). For illustration, note that any string of length $2$ also is already minimal: if

$A \rightarrow ab,$

the only possibly replacement grammar is

$A \rightarrow B$

$B \rightarrow ab$

which has greater length.

Assume that the claim holds for strings of length $n-1$, and assume further wlog that the letter $a$ added is the first. Using the usual notation, the length $n$ string is thus of form $a \alpha \beta$, with $\alpha$ or $\beta$ possibly empty (the notation will hopefully make sense when reading the below).

There are now 2 cases:

Case 1:
There is no reduction possible on top of those we can make for the string $\alpha \beta$ of length $n-1$. However, the reductions possible for this string can be made with $a$ appended to the left of $\alpha$ (or its leading factor). Assume that starting from the string $\alpha \beta$ it took $k \le n-1$ steps to reach a minimal grammar. Then it takes $k$ steps as well to reach it for a string of length $n$, and we are done.

Case 2:
It is easy to see (after thinking about it, and this is where the proof isn't fully formal as it should be a lemma) that any additional reduction in step $n$ means that the string is of form

$aA \alpha aA \beta aA \gamma,$

the sub-string $aA$ occuring at least three times in the string of length $n$, with any of the greek symbols possibly empty. In this case, we add an additional reduction for a new non-terminal $B$

$B \rightarrow aA$

This will not interfere with the reductions possible for the old string $\alpha \beta$ (we perform them 'with an $a$ added on the left as needed'; which, again, in a fully formal argument needs a lemma), so in this case too, we have shown the step $n-1$ to $n$.

Note: The meaning of the term 'length' should be clear from context (it could be the length of a string; and length as you defined in your comment below your question).

Comment: So you're saying you think it's true?